# Need to get page info after redirect with Mechanize in Python

Tags: python, forms, redirect, web, mechanize

I have spent a long time looking around the web for an answer, as well as many other stack overflow pages. None of them seem to quite answer my questions however. So the situation is that I'm inputting into forms and submitting, which brings me to the correct page. That page is basically a loading page as work is done by the website, which will normally take about 10-20 seconds. After it finishes it would normally redirect the user, but I can't figure out how to get my script to get redirected and read the forms on the new page. I can't format the URL to get to the page, it has to sit on the loading page for the website to do its work and redirect you to a custom url. How would I get my script to wait for a few seconds, then get redirected, then read the info from the new page?

Comment: This is much easier to do with selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use selenium, this is as easy as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com") 

# fill data in the form
first_name_element = driver.find_element_by_name("first_name")
first_name_element.send_keys("Abc")
last_name_element = driver.find_element_by_name("last_name")
last_name_element.send_keys("Xyz")

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #submit the form
time.wait(20) # wait for 20 sec

# do something here with your final redirected page 

browser.close()
```

The down side is that this will open a firefox window, the user actions would happen
automatically and all this would seem creepy.